# OpenAPI Generator jaxrs-spec adds unused imports, how to remove them?

Tags: openapi-generator

When using the OpenAPI Generator with the JAX-RS generator (jaxrs-spec), i am encountering a significant number of unused imports in the generated code.

How do i remove them except from doing it manually. Is there maybe a configuration option i've missed?

I tried using version 6.5.0 and 6.6.0 with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

First, the unused imports won't have any effect on your apps performance, and you should be excluding generated code from any linting tool.

That being said, if you absolutely must remove the unused imports, you can do so via the [Spotless Plugin](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless).  The spotless has both a maven and a gradle plugin, and you can see examples of how to use both in the mustache files for other generators.  Since the JAX-RS generator generates a pom.xml, I recommend checking out the [`pom.mustache` for the `ok-http generator`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/libraries/okhttp-gson/pom.mustache#L198) for an example of how to configure the plugin.

This is the bare minimum you would need

```xml
<properties>
    <spotless.version>2.27.2</spotless.version>
</properties>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${spotless.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <java>
            <removeUnusedImports/>
        </java>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can put that in your own code, or override the generated pom.xml using [openapi-generator mustache templating](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/templating.md) to ensure the plugin is always applied when the code is generated.